# Delete Bigtable row in Apache Beam 2.2.0

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

In `Dataflow 1.x` versions, we could use `CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable(TABLE_ID)` to create, update, and delete Bigtable rows. As long as a `DoFn` was configured to output a `Mutation` object, it could output either a `Put` or a `Delete`, and `CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable()` successfully created, updated, or deleted a row for the given RowID.

It seems that the new `Beam 2.2.0 API` uses `BigtableIO.write()` function, which works with `KV<RowID, Iterable<Mutation>>`, where the `Iterable` contains a set of row-level operations. I have found how to use that to work on Cell-level data, so it's OK to create new rows and create/delete columns, but how do we delete rows now, given an existing RowID?

Any help appreciated!

** Some further clarification:

From this document: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/dataflow-hbase I understand that changing the dependency ArtifactID from `bigtable-hbase-dataflow` to `bigtable-hbase-beam` should be compatible with Beam version 2.2.0 and the article suggests doing Bigtble writes (and hence Deletes) in the old way by using `CloudBigtableIO.writeToTable()`. However that requires imports from the `com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow` family of dependencies, which the Release Notes suggest is deprecated and shouldn't be used (and indeed it seems incompatible with the new Configuration classes/etc.)

** Further Update:

It looks like my `pom.xml` didn't refresh properly after the change from `bigtable-hbase-dataflow` to `bigtable-hbase-beam` ArtifactID. Once the project got updated, I am able to import from the 
`com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.*` branch, which seems to be working at least for the minimal test.

HOWEVER: It looks like now there are two different Mutation classes:
`com.google.bigtable.v2.Mutation` and
`org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation` ?

And in order to get everything to work together, it has to be specified properly which Mutation is used for which operation?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you should continue using `CloudBigtableIO` and `bigtable-hbase-beam`.  It shouldn't be too different from `CloudBigtableIO` in `bigtable-hbase-dataflow`.

`CloudBigtableIO` uses the HBase `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Mutation` and translates them into the Bigtable equivalent values under the covers

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Apache Beam 2.2.0 doesn't provide a native interface for deleting an entire row (including the row key) in Bigtable. The only full solution would be to continue using the `CloudBigtableIO` class as you already mentioned.

A different solution would be to just delete all the cells from the row. This way, you can fully move forward with using the `BigtableIO` class. However, this solution does NOT delete the row key itself, so the cost of storing the row key remains. If your application requires deleting many rows, this solution may not be ideal.

```java
import com.google.bigtable.v2.Mutation
import com.google.bigtable.v2.Mutation.DeleteFromRow

// mutation to delete all cells from a row
Mutation.newBuilder().setDeleteFromRow(DeleteFromRow.getDefaultInstance()).build()
```

Comment: Deleting all cells in a row is how one deletes an entire row.

Comment: When all cells in a row are deleted, does the row key get garbage collected at some point?

Comment: When a row is deleted (which is represented by deleting all cells), the  data that's on disk for that row is eventually garbage collected.

Comment: @SolomonDuskis Does that mean that the mutation https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-client/javadoc/com/google/bigtable/v2/Mutation.DeleteFromRow is how you delete a row in Bigtable?

Comment: That's correct.  A Mutation has 4 types: SetCell (use for HBase Puts), DeleteFromColumn, DeleteFromFamily and DeleteFromRow (which are all used for HBase Deletes).  You can see the protocol here: https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/bigtable/v2/data.proto#L444